# refill dataGridView that has dataSet with inner joins

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, binding, datagridview

I have dataGridView, that has dataSet, binding source and tableAdapter.
In dataSet binded by tableAdapter to dataGridView I have inner join's used.

Table Cars:
Car_ID, Client_ID, Model, LastOilChange, property....

Table Models:
ID_Model, NameOfModel, ID_Producent

Table Producents:
ID_Producent, NameOfProducent

DataGridView headers:
NameOfProducent, NameOfModel, LastOilChange, property...

... so inner join is used to connect Cars.Model with Model.ID_Model, and Model.ID_producent with Producents.ID_Producent.

When table loads on initializing form - everything is fine, and every values are in columns where they should be.

I don't know how to use filter for it? I want to select only Cars for some Client_ID and when i do it - Model and Producent are empty :/

I do it that way:

```
List<Car> ClientsCar = (from u in DB.Cars
                        where u.Client_ID == sometextbox.text
                        select u).ToList();
DataGridView.BindingSource = ClientsCar;
```

Please show me the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple (like always).

I've created a procedure that gets as argument a `ClientID`, and returns select for this client (with inner joins and other stuff). After that I've created a `DataSource` for `DataGridView` from that procedure, and used `TableAdapter` to fill it with the `GetData` method.

```
dataGridViewSamochodyPowiazaneKlienta.DataSource = this.wyszukajSamochodyKlientaTableAdapter.GetData(ID_klienta.ToString()).ToArray();
dataGridViewSamochodyPowiazaneKlienta.Refresh();
```

That solved my problem.